# Is it possible that the global filter does not affect the visualizations

Tags: kibana

I noticed that you can globally filter the data just by clicking values in visualizations, but is it possible to make it so that this filtering does not affect one or a few particular graphs?

I read that something similar can be done in mapping, but I don't have access to it.

Comment: As a quick answer no. In Kibana dashboards, global filter affects all visualization. As a workaround, you can have separate dashboards that you want to filter out. Or you can edit a visualization in dashboard and add filter in it.